# Some program occupy port 80. What is it?

Tags: port, netstat

I am trying to run netstat and this is what I got

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5550         TOSHIBA-PC:49319       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19872        TOSHIBA-PC:49456       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49190        TOSHIBA-PC:49191       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49191        TOSHIBA-PC:49190       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49287        TOSHIBA-PC:49288       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49288        TOSHIBA-PC:49287       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49289        TOSHIBA-PC:49290       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49290        TOSHIBA-PC:49289       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49291        TOSHIBA-PC:49292       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49292        TOSHIBA-PC:49291       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49313        TOSHIBA-PC:49314       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49314        TOSHIBA-PC:49313       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49315        TOSHIBA-PC:49316       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49316        TOSHIBA-PC:49315       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49319        TOSHIBA-PC:5550        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49350        TOSHIBA-PC:49351       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49351        TOSHIBA-PC:49350       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49352        TOSHIBA-PC:49353       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49353        TOSHIBA-PC:49352       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49354        TOSHIBA-PC:49355       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49355        TOSHIBA-PC:49354       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49456        TOSHIBA-PC:19872       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50553        TOSHIBA-PC:58934       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:58934        TOSHIBA-PC:50553       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59182        TOSHIBA-PC:59183       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59183        TOSHIBA-PC:59182       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59189        TOSHIBA-PC:59190       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59190        TOSHIBA-PC:59189       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59638        TOSHIBA-PC:59639       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59639        TOSHIBA-PC:59638       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.27:52802     180.76.2.25:http       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.27:53071     38.88.150.74:59593     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.27:53071     76.76.188.235:17302    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.27:53071     81:57712               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.27:53071     82-76-49-242:50082     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.27:53071     541E1D99:49454         LAST_ACK
```

No body is using port 80

I do not know what to do then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you believe some program is listening on port 80 for connections on your system, if you don't see "http" listed under the "Local Address" column in the output of your netstat command? You can filter the results to make sure you aren't overlooking it with `netstat -a | find /i "HTTP" | find "LISTENING"`

If you do see the system is listening on port 80 (HTTP), you can add the `-b` option to display the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port as suggested by Alex. Unlike `netstat -a`, though, `netstat -ab` requires privilege escalation, so you may see the message "The requested operation requires elevation." If you see that message you will need to [open a command prompt with administrator level access](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php).

Another alternative free GUI tool to find which process is listening on a particular port on a Microsoft Windows system is [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) from NirSoft. It will show the process name and the directory path for the location of the program associated with the process that has the port open.

Comment: +1 for both. I think this one is a the better answer

Comment: The question didn't specify Microsoft Windows, but the answer seems to.  Specifically, netstat -ab (or netstat -nab, which I prefer) is a solution specific to newer versions of Microsoft Windows (e.g., I think XP is okay, Win9x isn't).  Unix users might not be able to use the -b with netstat.  Unfortunately, the answer may be rather specific to what operating system is being used.  (fstat / lsof might be helpful?)

Comment: @ TOOGAM, though the poster didn't specify he is using Windows on TOSHIBA-PC, from the netstat output he posted, it appears he is using a Windows system. E.g., there are no "Recv-Q Send-Q" columns and 127.0.0.1 appears rather than localhost. Also, those using Linux seem less likely to assume others will know which operating system is being used on their system.

Answer (score 8):

Do `netstat -ab` to also find `LISTENING` state and which program. A program using your port 80 is likely a server listening on it. Or, use [tcpview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) for GUI-based listing.

Answer (score 0):

One of the usual suspects is Skype, it is using the port 80.